# Google Colab - ImportError: The class MatplotlibDrawer needs pylatexenc

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, qiskit, circuit-construction

When I run the following command

```
qc.draw(output='mpl')
```

for my circuit qc, I get this error:

```
ImportError: The class MatplotlibDrawer needs pylatexenc
```

How do I address this issue? Below an image of my problem

[image]

**Update** ------ 
Installation steps on Google Colaboratoy: 
`!pip install pylatexenc ?`.

The installation attempt (was successful and the installed `pylatexenc`  has version `2.7`.)

Comment: Have you tried installing pylatexenc with whichever package manager you are using?

Comment: yes i did but still not working @Rammus

Comment: What version of qiskit do you have?

Comment: I am using qiskit version '0.15.2' @Winona

Comment: @quantum_boy, can you please provide more information? How did you try to install `pylatexenc`? Did the installation fail? What message did you receive for the failed installation? Otherwise it'd be impossible for us to hep you out.

Comment: Thanks for the image. You have the latest version of Qiskit.

Comment: I am using google colab so this is how I installed it  `!pip install pylatexenc` @user9318

Comment: +1 vey good! The fact that you are using "google colab" is very important to know.  I've never used it before. I'll get back to you as soon as I find more information.

Comment: Meanwhile, I think it would be a good idea if you post your question on stackoverflow and tag `google-colaboratoy`.

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342408/how-do-i-install-python-packages-in-googles-colab. Also when you run the line `!pip install pylatexenc` in your notebook what is the output? Does it run without problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's an issue with latest Qiskit I've noticed. Use following command to downgrade it to previous version(0.16.1 specifically) for the time being.

> !pip install
> qiskit==0.16.1

Comment: yes It is working on v0.16.1 but problem is with v0.21.0 I think this problem is happning on notebooks but not on IDLE or pycharm @dushyanth

Answer (score 1):

The `0.15.2` is actually the version of your `qiskit-terra` package not Qiskit itself.
I'd suggest you to check the version by  `qiskit.__qiskit_version__`. See the [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/install.html#checking-which-version-is-installed).

If all packages have the latest version, you simply need to install `pylatexenc` in the same `env` where your Qiskit has been installed. Just by typing `pip install pylatexenc` in terminal!

In case you don't have the latest version of Qiskit.
You need to upgrade it first by `pip install qiskit --upgrade` and then install `pylatexenc`.

**Update** 
For Google Colab, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61212861/14162235) from Stackoverflow might be relevant.
`%pip install pylatexenc`

Comment: Yes I have done exactly the same but still showing same error. please see my question again this time I also have provided the Image. @user9318

Comment: I appreciate your effort you did for this problem brother but it is still not working. And I am taking your advise to post it on Stackoverflow. Thaknyou @user9318

Comment: @quantum_boy did you find a way around that?

Comment: No, Do you have solution?@dushyanth

Comment: @quantum_boy, you're welcome! Sorry couldn't help more! But I'm still curious to know what Google Colab throws out after you run the line `!pip install pylatexenc` of your code?

Comment: @dushyanth, if you have the same question/problem please "upvote" the question. This'll raise other's attention to provide answer.

Comment: I just found solution read my answer and thanks for you effort and time @user9318

Comment: I just found solution read my answer and thanks for you effort and time @dushyanth

Comment: I've also found the error mate. It has nothing to do with google collab. The issue is with the Qiskit version, I figured it when I was installe the Qiskit on my PC last night and had the same issue. I've rolled back to old version  and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

use `%matplotlin inline` before executing `draw('mpl')` here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027980/purpose-of-matplotlib-inline) for more info

Comment: Line magic function `%matplotlin` not found.
It shows this

Comment: @dushyanth, There is a type it should be `%matplotlib inline`.

Comment: %matplotlib inline even this doesn't fix it. I get the same error mentioned in the question ImportError: The class MatplotlibDrawer needs pylatexenc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, running same command ( with `!pip  install pylatexenc`) inside the jupyter notebook solved the issue!

Comment: Welcome on the QC SE! I suggest to write more about, how your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

I am using latest qiskit package:

```
{'qiskit-terra': '0.24.0', 'qiskit-aer': '0.12.0', 'qiskit-ignis': None, 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.20.2', 'qiskit': '0.43.0', 'qiskit-nature': None, 'qiskit-finance': None, 'qiskit-optimization': None, 'qiskit-machine-learning': None}
```

I had the same issue, which said MatplotlibDrawer needs pylatexenc. However, I installed the latest version of the package by pip.

My solution: I restarted the kernel, ran all lines and it works.